# I defined all of my variables as variants, but I'm still getting Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

'The part that's bolded is what the debugger is highlighting - I don't understand why it's not working.  I tried having `lat_origin`, `long_origin`, `dest_lat` and `dest_long` as variants in the function statement, but then it says I'm duplicating when I use the "Dim" statements.  If I don't include the dim statements in the function, then it says that my variables aren't defined and highlights "Radians," which is a standard excel function.

```
Option Explicit

Function LATLONDISTANCE(lat_origin As Single, long_origin As Single, dest_lat As Single, dest_long As Single) As Variant

    Worksheets("Combined").Activate

    ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 10).Select

    Dim lat_origin As Variant

    Dim long_origin As Variant

    Dim dest_lat As Variant

    Dim dest_long As Variant
'I don't want to include these "Dim statements, but if I don't, then "Radians" in the LATLONDISTANCE formula is highlighted, saying that it's not defined

    LATLONDISTANCE = 0.621371 * (6371.1 * ((2 * Asin(SQRT((Sin((Radians(lat_origin) - Radians(dest_lat)) / 2) ^ 2) + Cos(Radians(lat_origin)) * Cos(Radians(dest_lat)) * (Sin((Radians(long_origin) - Radians(dest_long)) / 2) ^ 2))))))

End Function

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

        Dim latlong(185, 1) As Variant
        Dim iCounter1 As Integer, iCounter2 As Integer, iCounter3 As Integer, iCounter4 As Integer

        Dim distance(185, 185) As Variant
        Dim lat_origin As Variant
        Dim long_origin As Variant
        Dim dest_lat As Variant
        Dim dest_long As Variant

        Worksheets("Combined").Activate
        Range("I2").Activate
        For iCounter1 = 0 To 1
            For iCounter2 = 0 To 185
                latlong(iCounter2, iCounter1) = ActiveCell.Offset(iCounter2, iCounter1).Value
            Next iCounter2
        Next iCounter1

        For iCounter1 = 0 To 1
            For iCounter2 = 0 To 185
                latlong(iCounter2, iCounter1) = ActiveCell.Offset(iCounter2, iCounter1).Value
            Next iCounter2
        Next iCounter1

        For iCounter4 = 0 To 185 Step 1
            lat_origin = latlong(iCounter4, 0)
            long_origin = latlong(iCounter4, 1)
            For iCounter3 = 0 To 185 Step 1
                dest_lat = latlong(iCounter3, 0)
                dest_long = latlong(iCounter3, 1)
                distance(iCounter4, iCounter3) = LATLONDISTANCE(lat_origin, long_origin, dest_lat, dest_long)
                Range(Cells(2, 14), Cells(187, 201)) = distance(iCounter4, iCounter3)
            Next iCounter3
        Next iCounter4

        For iCounter4 = 0 To 185 Step 1
            lat_origin = latlong(iCounter4, 0)
            long_origin = latlong(iCounter4, 1)
            For iCounter3 = 0 To 185 Step 1
                dest_lat = latlong(iCounter3, 0)
                dest_long = latlong(iCounter3, 1)
                distance(iCounter4, iCounter3) = LATLONDISTANCE(**lat_origin**, long_origin, dest_lat, dest_long)
                Range(Cells(2, 14), Cells(187, 201)) = distance(iCounter4, iCounter3)
            Next iCounter3
        Next iCounter4
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring all of your arguments as `Single`s

```
Function LATLONDISTANCE(lat_origin As Single, long_origin As Single, dest_lat As Single, dest_long As Single) As Variant
```

But then you try to pass them a `Variant`. You can't do that. You have to declare the variables as `Single`s too.

```
    Dim lat_origin As Single
    Dim long_origin As Single
    Dim dest_lat As Single
    Dim dest_long As Single
```

Comment: Thanks! When I went through to fix that, I got mired in defining excel functions.  Application.WorksheetFunction.Asin for example - all the other trigonometric functions work, but Asin returns runtime error 438 (object doesn't support this property or method)

Comment: You should ask a new question to get help with that. Please remember to do some debugging of your own and provide a [minimal example of the issue you're facing](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Often, going through that process will help you figure it out on your own. =)